# Find $n$ sets with nonempty pairwise intersections, no set a subset of another and $\bigcap_i A_i=\emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Or, $A_i\cap A_j\ne\emptyset$, $A_i\not\subseteq A_j$ for $i\ne j$, and $\bigcap_i A_i=\emptyset$.

An example for $n=4$:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How about
$$ A_i = \{ \{i,k\} \mid 1\le k\le n \} $$
which works for $n\ge 3$.

$n=2$ is not possible (nonempty *pairwise* intersections in that case conflicts directly with *all of them* having empty intersection).

$n=1$ is arguably possible by setting $A_1=\varnothing$, because there are no pairwise intersections to require nonemptiness of.

Comment: i did $A_i =\{1...n\}\setminus i$